# Completely uninstall Adobe CC

Tags: macos, high-sierra, adobe, adobe-photoshop

I want to get rid of all the services, background processes, and apps that would have been installed when I got CC.

The software has a heavy footprint from licensing daemons, always running update processes that use side channel loading and sync processes like these:

[image]
[image]

How can I uninstall everything related to Adobe CC from my computer?

Answer (score 16):

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed, you can do `brew uninstall --zap --cask --force adobe-creative-cloud`.

Take a look at [the Ruby script](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/a/adobe-creative-cloud.rb) this command executes to see what items it deletes and what actions it takes before and after these deletions take place.

Answer (score 7):

Every CC app has an uninstaller filed with the app.

[image]

These are repeated in the Utilities folder, in Adobe Installers.

The only one that doesn't is the Adobe Application Manager, for which there's an uninstaller [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html)

Answer (score 3):

Adobe also has a solution called [Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html) that can be used to remove most of the Adobe software.  It will skip Acrobat (it's Adobe, don't expect it to make sense).

For enterprise level removals it also can be run from a command line.  Unfortunately Adobe doesn't document all of the switches so it can be helpful to know that adding `--eulaAccepted=1` to your command line switches will allow the tool to run silently on macOS computers.  We use `--removeAll=ALL` as our command line switch to remove everything the tool can when running from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to completely uninstall apps is to use a third party app like App Clean, Dr. Cleaner, or one of several other apps in the App Store. I've used App Cleaner and it worked fine. This app worked after I deleted the app. App Cleaner popped open a message asking if I wanted to remove other files related to my deleted app. It listed the other files and then deleted them.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using 'cleaner' apps. Adobe provides uninstallers for their products, which you should use. Cleaner apps tend to encourage excessive file deletion, and usually come with other unnecessary features like emptying caches. They are just as capable of deleting required files as you are. Most 'cruft' left behind by apps amounts to only a handful of kilobytes.

Comment: I don't understand at all the sentence "This app worked after I deleted the app." Which version of Adobe CC did you uninstall with App Cleaner? I'm skeptical as @benwiggy was that it grabs all the items the official Adobe uninstall scripts do.